# How to activate Unity mode in VMware Workstation？

Tags: vmware, linux-mint

I create a virtual machine, Linux Mint 18. But I can't activate the Unity mode.
My system is windows 7 64bit. My vmware version is 12 pro.

Comment: Follow the instructions [here](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-8C477788-7700-4030-8C4A-039C02AABB74.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following features have reached end of life in Workstation 12 Pro and have been removed:

- Unity mode on Linux guest and host operating systems
- Integrated Virtual Debugger Visual Studio
- Connection to the VMware vCloud Air subscription service (The VMware vCloud Air OnDemand service is still fully supported)

Here is the [page](http://pubs.vmware.com/Release_Notes/en/workstation/12pro/workstation-12-release-notes.html).